# Tag "info" tab makes the site forget your default tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, sorting, tag-wiki, questions-tabs

Steps to repro, tested in Google Chrome and Firefox:

1. Click a tag.
2. Click the "info" tab.
3. Click the main "Questions" link.

You'll see that no tab is selected at the top and the votes sort is shown by default.

Comment: confirmed by me in firefox 4.0b1

Comment: Repro in IE8 and XP. Ideally, it should be like "Stats", which defaults to Newest (the others just stick between questions view and tag search).

Comment: 6-8 weeks, I laugh at you ... more like 6-8 minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this, cause otherwise Jeff would say:  "I told you so" and I would humbly admit he was right.

This does raise a bigger issue though that I think needs to be addressed.

Tag wiki pages are the **first** page we want new users to hit when the click on a tag, no point having this fancy shmancy feature if nobody can find it. So ... I think we need to open a separate issue to address this.

Comment: If we take new users to the info-tab, we should **really** highlight that they can also use the other buttons to get to the questions in that tab. They aren't always obvious. Maybe a wordy link "view the newest questions tagged `[frobble]`"

Comment: (after using chat, it really bothers me that [ret] doesn't add comments, but Jeff had a veto...)

Comment: @waffles, having the tag-wiki page the default raises another issue though - many tags will have no information for them at all for quite some time. For instance, I'm the all-time top answerer in the `[windows-desktop-gadgets]` tag, yet I only have 18 upvotes so I can't populate the tag-wiki. I think in those situations the user probably wouldn't want to see an empty info page.  Like you said, a separate discussion is probably needed.

Comment: yeah having them be the default is a profoundly bad idea.

Comment: @marc learn to love tab-space. I think chat is a very specialized scenario.

Comment: I've been using the new tag; and I think there should be something added to either the FAQ or below the tag to let me know when I'll be able to edit a tag wiki. Right now it's somewhere between 96 upvotes and 237 upvotes.